# "this.href" in jQuery is not returning the URL that the user clicked on.It is returning the active URL in the browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to display records using AJAX request and jQuery. The idea is to send some variables to a php script using `$.getJSON`. Then the script will return HTML code that has a code with the new data. However, this HTML code will also have the pagination links. So the links for the navigation are generated via jQuery and not pre-generated. The intention is when a user clicks on a any link of the navigation then a function called "recall" is called to generate a new html code.

The problem that I am having is when a use clicks on the navigation links (e.g. [5] or [Next])  jQuery is returning the page where the user is on and not the link that the user clicked.

This is my code

```
<script>

$(function(){

        //load activity when the page starts
        $(window).on('load', function(){
            //internal activities
            recall(1, -1, -1);

            //client activities
            recall_ext(1, -1);
        });


    });


        //this function will generate the internal activities
        function recall(page, mid, call_status){
        //display spinner "Loading....."
        $('#internalActivities,#mask1').addClass('loading');

        $.getJSON("ajax/loader-display-previous-calls.php", {
                account_id: <?php echo $account_id; ?>,
                page: page,
                mid_in_act: mid,
                status: call_status
            },function (data) {

                if (!data) return;  

                $('#activities_list').html('');
                $('#activities_list').html(data.msg).on('click', '.HistoricActivities', function(event) { 
                    event.preventDefault();
                    console.log(this.href); // this keeps returning undefined so I am unable to figure out what page the user want to visit next
                    recall(getURLParameter('page', this.href), $('#mid_in_act').val(), $('#call_status').val() );
                });    
            }).done( function(){

                //internal activities
                $('.HistoricActivities').on('click', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var clicked_url = $(this).attr('href');
                    console.log(clicked_url);  //this keeps returning undefined
                    recall(1, -1, -1);
                });

                //remove loading
                $('#internalActivities,#mask1').removeClass('loading');
            });     
        }


</script>
```

Comment: You should probably post the HTML, does `.HistoricActivities` match anchors that actually have `href` attributes ?

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing that the code works, are you sure that the HTML you getting back is correct? http://jsfiddle.net/joseftw/n6neK/

Comment: yes. it looks like I was missing the class. The issue now is that when I click on a page number it load the correct data but then a second later it reload page 1 all over again. Why it this happening?

Comment: @adeneo   if you post an answer I will make it as the correct answer. you lead me to the truth. I figured it out from there.